# download not working and image not showing

Tags: python, html, django

I want to create a download link using the anchor tag but it is not working and the image is not showing either

```
<td><img src="{{book.book_image}}" alt="{{book.name}}" width="60px" height="50p"></td>
<td>{{book.book_name}}</td>
<td>{{book.author_name}}</td>
<td>{{book.subject}}</td>
<td><a href="{{book.file}}" download>Download</a></td>
```

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank="")
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files/", null=True, verbose_name='file ')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    book_add_time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now())
    book_add_date = models.DateField(default=date.today())
```

Comment: Share the root `urls.py`

Answer (score 1):

You should work with `.file.url`:

```
<td><a href="{{ book.file.url }}" download>Download</a></td>
```

in the root `urls.py` you should serve media files in *development* mode, in production, you will need to configure the web server (apache, nginx, etc.) for this:

```
# project_name/urls.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = (
    [
        # …
    ]
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
)
```

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

---

> **Note**: It is often *not* a good idea to have a separate [**`DateField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField) and [**`TimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TimeField): due to daylight saving time, certain combinations are not per se possible, others can be duplicated, search queries will take more effort, and it will require more storage. You might want to consider using a [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) instead.